# Java Jolt bazaarvoice nested array

Tags: java, jolt

I am using Jolt to transform data from

```
{
  "Data": {
    "ROOT": {
      "MODIFIED_DATE": "2018-06-27T13:53:47.8",
      "A1": [
        {
          "FLD1": "BB",
          "A2": [
            {
              "FLD2": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "FLD1": "AA",
          "A2": [
            {
              "FLD2": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "metaData": {
    "FLD3": "5f3c4"
  }
}
```

To

```
    {
          "modifiedDate": "2018-06-27T13:53:47.8",
          "a1": [
            {
              "fld1": "BB",
              "a2": [
                {
                  "fld2": 1
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "fld1": "AA",
              "a2": [
                {
                  "fld2": 2
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
         fld3: "5f3c4"
        }
```

My spec is

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Data": {
        "ROOT": {
          "MODIFIED_DATE": "modifiedDate",
          "A1": {
            "*": {
              "FLD1": "a1[&1]",
              "A2": {
                "*": {
                  "FLD2": "a2[&2].fld2"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "metaData": {
        "FLD3": "fld3"
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {}
    }
]
```

But it doesn't work properly. What have i missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Data": {
        "ROOT": {
          "MODIFIED_DATE": "modifiedDate",
          "A1": {
            "*": {
              "FLD1": "a1[&1].fld1",
              "A2": {
                "*": {
                  "FLD2": "a1[&3].a2[&1].fld2"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "metaData": {
        "FLD3": "fld3"
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {}
    }
]
```